# GRUB rescue : unknown filesystem, but working on another PC

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

Standard debian install for web server. Last night there was a power outage, then i restarted the server but stuck on grub rescue. So i pull the hard drive then put it in my PC. Checked all filesystem and it was ok. Tried to boot to it with my PC and its working with all files intact. After that i put it back to the server and the weird thing is, its still stuck on grub rescue with unknown filesystem on all partition.

Comment: Have you checked the boot order is still what it should be?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, but i found the solution: resetting the cmos solve the problem.

Comment: That would be indeed my other suggestion :)